# How do I pass a variable during class instantiate in one file to another?

Tags: php, class, oop, variables

I have 3 files, 2 of the files instantiate my `myclass` class. To determine which file they came from I want to pass a variable through to the class and then be able to output different content.

```
<?php

// File 1

$file1variable = '1';
$go = new myclass( $file1variable );

// File 2

$file2variable = '2';
$go = new myclass( $file2variable );

// File3

class myclass {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->display();
    }

    public function display() {

        if( $file1variable ) {
            echo 'file1';
        } elseif( $file2variable ) {
            echo 'file2';
        }


    }

}

?>
```

I have read up on reflection classes and this article [PHP: How to instantiate a class with arguments from within another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858254/php-how-to-instantiate-a-class-with-arguments-from-within-another-class) but can't seem to get this to work for my scenario.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: pass it to `__contruct($var)` and write it to private var. OR write a setter and call that _after_ contructing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `__FILE__` which this will give complete path of the file as an input to your class.

For getting just filename instead of `__FILE__` use this `explode("/", __FILE__)[count(explode("/", __FILE__))-1]`

**File 1:**

```
<?php
$go = new myclass( __FILE__ );
?>
```

**File 2:**

```
<?php
$go = new myclass( __FILE__ );
```

**File3**

```
<?php
class myclass {

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $this->display($filename);
    }

    public function display($filename) {

        if( $filename == 'some_x.php' ) {
            echo 'file1';
        } elseif( $filename == 'some_y.php') {
            echo 'file2';
        }


    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use the variable rather than `__FILE__` but the principle works for me :)

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge Welcome .. :)